# CSS border-image compatibility bug

Tags: css

i have problem with `border-image` in mozilla and safari, in chrome it works, but in other browsers no
the code:

```
border-width: 50px;
-moz-border-width: 50px;
-webkit-border-width: 50px;
border-image: url('/img/border.png') 50 50 round;
-webkit-border-image: url('/img/border.png') 50 50 round;
-moz-border-image: url('/img/border.png') 50 50 round;
```

did anyone have the same problem? thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is `border: 50px solid transparent;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P7JTQ/)

```
<div>Demo</div>

div {
    border:50px solid transparent;
    border-image: url('YOUR_URL') 50 50 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url('YOUR_URL') 50 50 round;
    -moz-border-image: url('YOUR_URL') 50 50 round;
}
```

Or add these in your CSS declaration

```
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
```

Note: You don't have to use `proprietary` properties for `border-width`

Comment: Working fine for me in Firefox as well. @KubajsHavel You may want to put together a jsFiddle or something to show your issue so others can test it out themselves.

Comment: but what about safari @Mr.Alien ?

Comment: @KubajsHavel I don't have that installed but if it works on Chrome, it will possibly work on Safari as well